# Extending MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools

What is MooTool's equivalent of this jQuery snippet:

```
jQuery.fn.doSomething = function() {

};
```

...which allows me to do this:

```
$("#myElement").doSomething();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the Element class by using [implement](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class#Class:implement) method.

```
Element.implement({
   doSomething: function(){alert('It works')}
});

$("myElement").doSomething();
```